# Azure B2C Custom policies login error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I created custom policies on Azure B2C following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom).

I used my B2C_1A_signup_signin custom policy for sign up without problems.
When I tried to sign in with the created user, the sign in form throws the error: Invalid username or password.

I linked the policy to Application Insights and I found this error:
Exception of type 'Web.TPEngine.Providers.BadArgumentRetryNeededException' was thrown.

The same happens when I try to use a custom ProfileEdit policy.

When I use my custom PasswordReset policy it works well.

I couldn't find information about the Web.TPEngine.Providers.BadArgumentRetryNeededException error. What does it mean?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double check the client id and resource id you are using to log users in, AD will always show connection issues as invalid username/.password for security reasons

Comment: I didn't know connection issues were handled in that way. Thanks for the additional info